# Flutter: DioError [DioErrorType.RESPONSE]: Http status error [500]

Tags: flutter, http, dio

I was asked to resolve some problems in flutter app
Now I face problem I don't know what reason to...

The app start with signup page, when the user create new account the app send verification mail via Firebase

**The situation is:** when I try to signup new account, or login to any account
The app keep loading and no verification mail send
and in log I face the error

**DioError [DioErrorType.RESPONSE]: Http status error [500]**

Through my research on the problem, I know that the cause is:
The sever responded with **InternalServerError** but dio sees this as an exception
but I'm not sure, what shall I do to fix this error

So, I need help

**here the log**

```
I/flutter (30836): ╔╣ Request ║ POST 
I/flutter (30836): ║  https://myBackendDomain.com/carRent/api/index.php/auth/send_email_to_user
I/flutter (30836): ╚══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
I/flutter (30836): ╔ Headers 
I/flutter (30836): ╟ content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
I/flutter (30836): ╟ contentType: application/json; charset=utf-8
I/flutter (30836): ╟ followRedirects: true
I/flutter (30836): ╟ connectTimeout: 60000
I/flutter (30836): ╟ receiveTimeout: 60000
I/flutter (30836): ╚══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
I/flutter (30836): ╔ Body 
I/flutter (30836): ╟ emailto: abc@abc.com
I/flutter (30836): ╟ text: Your Email verification OTP is 690139
I/flutter (30836): ╟ subject: Verification
I/flutter (30836): ╚══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
I/flutter (30836): ║ {emailto: abc@abc.com, text: Your Email verification OTP is 690139, subject: Verification}
I/flutter (30836): 
I/flutter (30836): ╔╣ Request ║ POST 
I/flutter (30836): ║  https://myBackendDomain.com/carRent/api/index.php/auth/send_email_to_user
I/flutter (30836): ╚══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
I/flutter (30836): ╔ Headers 
I/flutter (30836): ╟ content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
I/flutter (30836): ╟ Client-Service: frontend-client
I/flutter (30836): ╟ Auth-Key: simplerestapi
I/flutter (30836): ╟ contentType: application/json; charset=utf-8
I/flutter (30836): ╟ responseType: ResponseType.json
I/flutter (30836): ╟ followRedirects: true
I/flutter (30836): ╟ connectTimeout: 60000
I/flutter (30836): ╟ receiveTimeout: 60000
I/flutter (30836): ╚══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
I/flutter (30836): ╔ Body 
I/flutter (30836): ╟ emailto: abc@abc.com
I/flutter (30836): ╟ text: Your Email verification OTP is 690139
I/flutter (30836): ╟ subject: rentors
I/flutter (30836): ╚══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
I/flutter (30836): ║ {emailto: abc@abc.com, text: Your Email verification OTP is 690139, subject: Verification}
I/flutter (30836): 
I/flutter (30836): ╔╣ DioError ║ Status: 500 Internal Server Error
I/flutter (30836): ║  https://myBackendDomain.com/carRent/api/index.php/auth/send_email_to_user
I/flutter (30836): ╚══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
I/flutter (30836): ╔ DioErrorType.response
I/flutter (30836): ╚══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
I/flutter (30836): 
I/flutter (30836): DioError [DioErrorType.response]: Http status error [500]
I/flutter (30836): 
I/flutter (30836): ╔╣ DioError ║ Status: 500 Internal Server Error
I/flutter (30836): ║  https://myBackendDomain.com/carRent/api/index.php/auth/send_email_to_user
I/flutter (30836): ╚══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
I/flutter (30836): ╔ DioErrorType.response
I/flutter (30836): ╚══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
I/flutter (30836): 
I/flutter (30836): DioError [DioErrorType.response]: Http status error [500]
I/flutter (30836): runZonedGuarded: Caught error in my root zone.
I/flutter (30836): ----------------FIREBASE CRASHLYTICS----------------
I/flutter (30836): Unhandled error DioError [DioErrorType.response]: Http status error [500]
I/flutter (30836): Source stack:
I/flutter (30836): #0      DioMixin.fetch (package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart:473:35)
I/flutter (30836): #1      DioMixin.request (package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart:468:12)
I/flutter (30836): #2      DioMixin.post (package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart:91:12)
I/flutter (30836): #3      sendEmail (package:rentors/repo/LoginRepo.dart:73:30)
I/flutter (30836): #4      LoginBloc.mapEventToState (package:rentors/bloc/LoginBloc.dart:36:26)
I/flutter (30836): <asynchronous suspension>
I/flutter (30836):  occurred in Instance of 'LoginBloc'.
I/flutter (30836): #0      DioMixin.fetch.<anonymous closure> (package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart:628:7)
I/flutter (30836): #1      _rootRunBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:1450:47)
I/flutter (30836): #2      _CustomZone.runBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:1342:19)
I/flutter (30836): #3      _FutureListener.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:162:22)
I/flutter (30836): #4      Future._propagateToListeners.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:778:47)
I/flutter (30836): #5      Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:799:13)
I/flutter (30836): #6      Future._completeError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:574:5)
I/flutter (30836): #7      _SyncCompleter._completeError (dart:as
I/flutter (30836): 
I/flutter (30836): #0      BlocBase.onError.<anonymous closure> (package:bloc/src/bloc.dart:743:7)
I/flutter (30836): #1      BlocBase.onError (package:bloc/src/bloc.dart:744:6)
I/flutter (30836): #2      _rootRunBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:1450:47)
I/flutter (30836): #3      _CustomZone.runBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:1342:19)
I/flutter (30836): #4      _CustomZone.runBinaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1252:7)
I/flutter (30836): #5      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendError.sendError (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:360:15)
I/flutter (30836): #6      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendError (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:378:7)
I/flutter (30836): #7      _BufferingStreamSubscription._addError (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:280:7)
I/flutter (30836): #8      _SyncBroadcastStreamController._sendError.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/broadcast_stream_controller.dart:392:20)
I/flutter (30836): #9      _BroadcastStreamController._forEachListener (dart:async/broadcast_stream_controller.dart:322:15)
I/flutter (30836): #10     _SyncBroadcastStreamController._sendError (dart:async/broadcast_stream_controller.dart:391:5)
I/flutter (30836): #11     _BroadcastStreamController._addError (dart:async/broadcast_stream_controller.dart:289:5)
I/flutter (30836): #12     _ro
I/flutter (30836): ----------------------------------------------------
```

**UPDATE**
I was update the code by use try {} to catch the error

```
I/flutter (17126): DioError [DioErrorType.response]: Http status error [500]
I/flutter (17126):  DioError [DioErrorType.response]: Http status error [500]
I/flutter (17126): Source stack:
I/flutter (17126): #0      DioMixin.fetch (package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart:473:35)
I/flutter (17126): #1      DioMixin.request (package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart:468:12)
I/flutter (17126): #2      DioMixin.post (package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart:91:12)
I/flutter (17126): #3      sendEmail (package:rentors/repo/LoginRepo.dart:78:43)
I/flutter (17126): #4      LoginBloc.mapEventToState (package:rentors/bloc/LoginBloc.dart:36:26)
I/flutter (17126): <asynchronous suspension>
I/flutter (17126): runZonedGuarded: Caught error in my root zone.
I/flutter (17126): ----------------FIREBASE CRASHLYTICS----------------
I/flutter (17126): NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'message' was called on null.
I/flutter (17126): Receiver: null
I/flutter (17126): Tried calling: message
I/flutter (17126): 
I/flutter (17126): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:38:5)
I/flutter (17126): #1      SignupScreenState.initState.<anonymous closure> (package:rentors/screen/SignupScreen.dart:54:50)
I/flutter (17126): #2      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1434:47)
I/flutter (17126): #3      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1335:19)
I/flutter (17126): #4      _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1244:7)
I/flutter (17126): #5      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:341:11)
I/flutter (17126): #6      _DelayedData.perform (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:591:14)
I/flutter (17126): #7      _StreamImplEvents.handleNext (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:706:11)
I/flutter (17126): #8      _PendingEvents.schedule.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:663:7)
I/flutter (17126): #9      _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1418:47)
I/flutter (17126): #10     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1328:19)
I/flutter (17126): #11     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1236:7)
I/flutter (17126): #12     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1276:23)
I/flutter (17126): #13     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1426:13)
I/flutter (17126): #14     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1328:19)
I/flutter (17126): ----------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Catch `DioError` and handle an internal server error.

```
try {
...
  final result = await dio.post('https://myBackendDomain.com/carRent/api/index.php/auth/send_email_to_user', data: ...);
...
} on DioError catch (e) {
  // The request was made and the server responded with a status code
  // that falls out of the range of 2xx and is also not 304.
...
}
```

See [Handling Errors](https://pub.dev/packages/dio#handling-errors) for details.